# What are the requierements to sniff UDP packets in a Wireless Ad-Hoc network?

Tags: wifi, iptables, routing, udp, ad-hoc-network

In a wireless Ad-Hoc network,
I have two computers which communicates in UDP together from 192.168.1.3 to 192.168.1.5

I have a third computer (192.168.1.6) which wants to listen to the packets which are not addressed to it. I can see the packets with `tcpdump` (which sets the wireless card in promiscuous mode).

To redirect the packets, I am using :

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5
```

Is it the only rule I need to use? Why isn't it working? Did I miss other requirements?

Comment: You are asking about sniffing packets, yet you want to forward them ? What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to instruct the 192.168.1.3 machine that it should reach the .5 machine **over** the .6 machine (depending on the `route` command syntax insert `gw` between the IP addresses):

```
route add 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.6
```

...and on the .6 machine ip forwarding needs to be enabled, which can be done by `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (note the space after the `1`).